# SLAM with inclined LIDAR & IMU for navigation and terrain mapping

Tags: slam, imu, navigation, gmapping, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy there,

I never worked with SLAM and was wondering if i can use it for my application:

I am moving with a remote controlled vehicle over uneven terrain and want to control the height of a LIDAR Sensor. The Sensor will be mounted inclined in order to scan the upcoming terrain and everything that happens beside the robot.

As a first approach i wanted to take a median of the cross section of the upcoming terrain and use this information to predict the movement of the robot when the bump or hole in the terrain is reached. In order to be able to detect if this point is reached i wanted to use SLAM since i have no odometry information.

Can I use SLAM (gmapping or hector_slam) with the inclined LIDAR to get a position information in order to estimate if a bump is reached or not?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262015/slam-with-inclined-lidar-&-imu-for-navigation-and-terrain-mapping/) by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2017-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Intuitively speaking, SLAM approaches generally work by comparing incoming sensor data to a map and localizing within that map. Driving forward with only an inclined LIDAR, you won't be able to localize using standard SLAM approaches, as incoming sensor data cannot be compared to existing map information (since the LIDAR always sees a completely new "slice" of the environment that is not part of the map generated so far). It sounds like some sort of odometry estimate would be sufficient for your application, so generating such an estimate would possibly be sufficient. If you have no way to get wheel odometry, other (low cost) options are just using a constant velocity model (i.e. assume your platform moves with fixed velocity, possibly fuse with IMU data) or using one of the visual SLAM/odometry approaches out there such as ORBSLAM2, libviso2 etc.

Of course, another, more expensive option is using a second horizontal LIDAR and using that to do "standard" SLAM.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2017-05-18**:
Thank you Stefan for your answer,

i will investigate some time into your idea!

Best,
Michael